# Spring Data Neo4j - findById method throws an invalid query exception after upgrading to Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have been working on a micro-service created using Spring Boot with Neo4j as the database. The two relevant entities within it Product and AccessoryRelation are thus:

```
@NodeEntity
@QueryEntity
public class Product extends AbstractNeo4jEntity {

@Index(primary = true, unique = true)
private String productId;

@Transient
private String market;

@JsonIgnore
@Relationship(type = "HAS_ACCESSORY")
private Set<AccessoryRelation> relations = new HashSet<>();

public Product() {

}

public Product(final String productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}

public String getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public String getMarket() {
    return market;
}

public void setMarket(final String market) {
    this.market = market;
}

public Set<AccessoryRelation> getRelations() {
    return new HashSet<>(relations);
}

public void addAccessory(final Product accessory) {
    Assert.notNull(accessory, "Accessory product can not be null");
    Assert.hasText(accessory.getProductId(),
            "Accessory product should have a valid identifier");
    Assert.hasText(accessory.getMarket(),
            "Accessory product should be available atleast in one market");
    Assert.isTrue(!this.equals(accessory),
            "A product can't be an accessory of itself.");

    final AccessoryRelation relation = this.relations.stream() //
            .filter(rel -> rel.getAccessory().equals(accessory)) //
            .findAny() //
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                final AccessoryRelation newRelation = new AccessoryRelation(this,
                        accessory, Sets.newHashSet());
                this.relations.add(newRelation);
                return newRelation;
            });

    relation.addMarket(accessory.getMarket());
}

public void removeAccessory(final Product accessory) {
    Assert.notNull(accessory, "Accessory product can not be null");
    Assert.hasText(accessory.getProductId(),
            "Accessory product should have a valid identifier");
    Assert.hasText(accessory.getMarket(),
            "Accessory product should be available atleast in one market");

    final Optional<AccessoryRelation> relation = this.relations.stream() //
            .filter(rel -> rel.getAccessory().equals(accessory)) //
            .findAny();

    if (relation.isPresent()) {
        relation.get().removeMarket(accessory.getMarket());

        if (relation.get().getMarkets().isEmpty()) {
            this.relations.remove(relation.get());
        }
    }
}

public void removeAccessories() {
    this.relations.clear();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(obj instanceof Product)) {
        return false;
    }

    final Product product = (Product) obj;

    return new EqualsBuilder() //
            .append(getProductId(), product.getProductId()) //
            .isEquals();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder() //
            .append(getProductId()) //
            .toHashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ToStringBuilder(this) //
            .append("ProductId", getProductId()) //
            .toString();
}
}



@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS_ACCESSORY")
public class AccessoryRelation extends AbstractNeo4jEntity {

@StartNode
private Product product;

@EndNode
private Product accessory;

private Set<String> markets = new HashSet<>();

public AccessoryRelation() {

}

public AccessoryRelation(final Product product, final Product accessory,
        final Set<String> markets) {
    this.product = product;
    this.accessory = accessory;
    this.markets = markets;
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(final Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public Product getAccessory() {
    return accessory;
}

public void setAccessory(final Product accessory) {
    this.accessory = accessory;
}

public Set<String> getMarkets() {
    return new HashSet<>(markets);
}


public void addMarket(final String market) {
    this.markets.add(market);
}


public void removeMarket(final String market) {
    this.markets.remove(market);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(obj instanceof AccessoryRelation)) {
        return false;
    }

    final AccessoryRelation relation = (AccessoryRelation) obj;

    return new EqualsBuilder() //
            .append(getProduct(), relation.getProduct()) //
            .append(getAccessory(), relation.getAccessory()) //
            .isEquals();
}

@Override
public final int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder() //
            .append(getProduct()) //
            .append(getAccessory()) //
            .toHashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ToStringBuilder(this) //
            .append("Product", getProduct()) //
            .append("Accessory", getAccessory()) //
            .append("Markets", getMarkets()) //
            .toString();
}
```

}

For JUnit test cases I am using nosqlunit-neo4j version 1.0.0-rc.5  and an embedded databsase.

Now I have the findById(productId) method which would return the Product along with the associated AccessoryRelation objects. However, after upgrading to Spring Boot 2, this method does not work. It throws an exception thus:

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.exception.UncategorizedNeo4jException: 
Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax; 
Description: Invalid input '|': expected whitespace, comment, a 
relationship pattern, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, 
CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', 
"<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ']' (line 1, column 113 (offset: 
112))
"MATCH (n:`Product`) WHERE n.`productId` = { id } WITH n RETURN n,[ [ 
(n)-[r_h1:`HAS_ACCESSORY`]->(p1:`Product`) | [ r_h1, p1 ] ] ]"

^; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error 
executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax; 
Description: Invalid input '|': expected whitespace, comment, a 
relationship pattern, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, 
CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', 
"<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ']' (line 1, column 113 (offset: 
112)) 
"MATCH (n:`Product`) WHERE n.`productId` = { id } WITH n RETURN n,[ [ 
(n)-[r_h1:`HAS_ACCESSORY`]->(p1:`Product`) | [ r_h1, p1 ] ] ]"
```

By the looks of it, it is treating the '|' character as an invalid character within the query. However, when I run the same query in a neo4 3.4.9 instance on the browser, it works fine. No syntax errors on that one. The application has a default neo4j version of 2.3.3 which coming from the nosqlunit dependency. I have tried including neo4j 3.4.9 dependencies in my pom, but that creates a whole set of new problems.

The following is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF- 
8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.itDirectory>src/it/java</project.build.itDirectory>
    <neo4j-cypher-dsl.version>2.3-RELEASE</neo4j-cypher-dsl.version>
    <querydsl.version>4.1.4</querydsl.version>
    <querydsl-apt.version>1.1.3</querydsl-apt.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-lucene3</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- This jar is used by CypherQueryDSL at runtime. If its not present
        in classpath then java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.search.Query
        error is thrown -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>citrus-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>citrus-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>citrus-java-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j-cypher-dsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lordofthejars</groupId>
        <artifactId>nosqlunit-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-rc.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openpojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>openpojo</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nl.jqno.equalsverifier</groupId>
        <artifactId>equalsverifier</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
        <version>6.0_ALPHA</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>product-accessory-service</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl-apt.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/querydsl</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.13</version>
            <configuration>
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? Could anyone please help me out in resolving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a neo4j version > 3.1 ?

Comment: Yeah neo4j 3.4.9

Comment: it's weird, have you tested the query in your error directly in Neo4j ?